# Too many arguments in call during compilation

Tags: go

I would like to use a package in my Go project, but I can't even compile the code successfully because of the following error:

```
C:\Users\usr01\go\pkg\mod\github.com\alethio\web3-multicall-go@v0.0.15\multicall\viewcall.go:259:8: assignment mismatch: 1 variable but wrapperArgs.Unpack returns 2 values 

C:\Users\usr01\go\pkg\mod\github.com\alethio\web3-multicall-go@v0.0.15\multicall\viewcall.go:259:37: too many arguments in call to wrapperArgs.Unpack
```

This happens when I start my program with `go run`, I assume during the compilation because the code which uses the package doesn't get called. I am new to this language, but what I could investigate is the problem occurs before the 259. line of the [viewcall.go file](https://github.com/Alethio/web3-multicall-go/blob/master/multicall/viewcall.go) which belongs to the [web3-go-multicall package](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/alethio/web3-multicall-go/multicall).

This is where the problem occurs:

```
data, err := wrapperArgs.Unpack(rawBytes)
```

What I don't understand, why this issue happens anyway? Because both returned variables are assigned to `data` and `err` so the  `assignment mismatch: 1 variable but wrapperArgs.Unpack returns 2 values` error seems incorrect for me.

```
wrapperArgs := abi.Arguments{
    {
        Name: "BlockNumber",
        Type: uint256Type,
    },
    {
        Name: "Returns",
        Type: returnType,
    },
}
data, err := wrapperArgs.Unpack(rawBytes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have linked the code in master, but according to logs that you have provided you are on version `v0.0.15`. And in that version there is only 1 argument on the left side and 2 arguments passed to a function - https://github.com/Alethio/web3-multicall-go/blob/v0.0.15/multicall/viewcall.go#L259

Probably 2 libraries (`github.com/Alethio/web3-multicall-go` and `github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum` or some child of that) have incompatible versions.

Comment: This solved the problem. I replaced v.0.0.15 with the master and works fine.